# Use batch file to copy first 6 lines to a new txt file

Tags: batch-file, copy, lines

I have tried a dozen different ways and cannot get it right.

I have many text files in different folders, so I would like to reference the input file as a variable eg: *.txt (just use whatever txt file is in the same folder as the bat file).

I need to copy the first 6 lines and paste them into a new txt file.
I would like to name it (but not essential) SAMPLE_original_txt_file_name

EG:

```
Input = text01.txt
Output = SAMPLE_text01.txt (this would contain the first 6 complete lines from text01.txt)
```

I would appreciate any help as my head now needs stitches from banging it too much against a wall...

Comment: Do you have cygwin installed? A simple `for` loop and `head -6` would make this utterly trivial.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF "%~1" == "" (ECHO Usage: %~nx0 filemask& GOTO :EOF)
FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR /B %1') DO (
  <"%%I" (
    FOR /L %%I IN (1,1,6) DO (
      SET line=
      SET /P line=
      SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
      ECHO(!line!
      ENDLOCAL
    )
  ) >"%%~dpISAMPLE_%%~nxI"
)
```

The above script expects an argument, which is a file mask, like `*.txt`. It also supports masks completed with (existing) paths. Whether the path is specified or not, the output sample files are created in the same directory as the original ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set count=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (text01.txt) do (
call :counter %%i
)
goto :eof
:counter
rem echo count is %count%
set /a count+=1
if %count% lss 7 echo %* >> SAMPLE_text01.txt
GOTO :eof
```