# batch to copy FIRST line of multiple text files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need the batch code to copy the FIRST line of multiple text files into a new text file and append original filenames to each line, and if possible a way of editing the batch code to any LINE number one wants.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use batch file to copy first 6 lines to a new txt file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044146/use-batch-file-to-copy-first-6-lines-to-a-new-txt-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses a helper batch file called `findrepl.bat` from - https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfdldmcb6vwi9xc/findrepl.bat

Place `findrepl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or on the path.

```
@echo off
set linenum=1
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
   type "%%a"|findrepl /o:%linenum%:%linenum% >>tmp.tmp
)
move /y tmp.tmp "Result.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
    set "line="
    set /p "line="<"%%~a"
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: Thank you, could you edit it so it gives the result in an output.txt file? Thank yhu

Comment: `echo !line! >> output.txt` ?