# Batch File To Copy Every Line In .txt File And Then Create New .txt File For Each Line

Tags: batch-file

I have .txt file contain 297 line, i want every line of that copied into new .txt file, so it will contain 297 file, for file name each file like this line1.txt line2.txt line3.txt, it possible using batch?

I have try using findrepl.bat and instruction form here [batch to copy FIRST line of multiple text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19935669/batch-to-copy-first-line-of-multiple-text-files/19944265#19944265) but thats script for first line only.

Comment: Please help yourself. This website is not a free code-factory. Have you made any effort whatsoever to solve this problem?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Also, keep in mind that Windows has restrictions on filename length and certain characters (e.g., "\").  Perhaps there is a better approach to whatever you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

`FOR /F` is what you want, with the use of `SET /A` to numerically increment a variable. Because CMD/batch is really only a punch card reader pretending to be a shell, the contents of `source_file.txt` can cause the script to break. In particular, if it has any special shell characters (like < > ! " or &), the shell will interpret those as special characters and not just echo them to the output file.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET LINENO=1
FOR /F "delims=" %%l IN (source_file.txt) DO (
    ECHO %%l>file!LINENO!.txt
    SET /A LINENO=LINENO+1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should split a file and create separate files for every line.

The filenames will be the same as each line.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do >>"%%a.txt" echo %%a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in (
    'findstr /n "^" "file.txt"'
) do echo(%%b>line%%a.txt
endlocal
```