# How To Copy Every 2 Line And Paste It Into New File In Batch

Tags: batch-file

I have search any reference regarding my plan to copy every 2 line and them paste it into new file. I found some good reference but it for copy every line not every 2 line you can check here [Batch File To Copy Every Line In .txt File And Then Create New .txt File For Each Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003175/batch-file-to-copy-every-line-in-txt-file-and-then-create-new-txt-file-for-eac)

Can i copy every 2 line from .txt file and paste it to another automatic generated .txt file that contain my 2 line from .txt source?

Some example source.txt like this:

mango
orange
apple
grape
pear
banana
papaya
etc.

i want to split it into every 2 line in new .txt file, result like this:

filename new.txt contain:
mango
orange

filename new2.txt contain:
apple
grape

filename new3.txt contain:
pear
banana

any someone to know the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way  ;

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set lines_per_file=2

set lineno=1
set mod=
set filenumber=0

for /f "delims=" %%l in (the.file) do (
    set /a mod=!lineno! %% !lines_per_file!
    if !mod! equ 1 set /a filenumber = filenumber + 1

    echo %%l >> file!filenumber!.txt

    set /a lineno=lineno + 1    
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "destadd="
SET "added="
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q22022330.txt) DO (
 >>new!destadd!.txt ECHO(%%a 
 IF DEFINED added (SET "added="&SET /a destadd+=1) ELSE (SET added=Y)
 IF !destadd!==1 SET destadd=2
)

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q22022330.txt` for my testing.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Magoo :-) your script work for me too, nice!