# Batch File: delete lines in a bunch of txt files

Tags: batch-file

i've got a problem with saving txt files in a loop i made to delete the first three rows of the txt files.
My code so far is the following:

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count=1
for %%a in ("C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\conduct\*.txt") do (
echo %%a
Copy NUL C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\conducterei\conduct!count!.txt
    for /f "skip=3 tokens=*" %%g in (%%a) do (
    >>"C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\conducterei\conduct!count!.txt" echo %%g
    )
set /a "count+=1"
)

pause
```

I read that the For /f loop does not accept wildcards so i did a nested loop but now i have the problem with copying the text saved in the %%g variable.
DOS prompts that my destination folder does not exist, but i just created it with COPY NUL in the first for loop.

The command in the second for-loop seems not correct to save %%g in a text file.
The original text file looks like that:

```
blabla
blank
blank
4 5 6 7 8 9 2143
1 2 6 7 1 0 9763
. . . . . . .
```

I only want the numbers in my new text files! I already read in this thread ([Batch File To Copy Every Line In .txt File And Then Create New .txt File For Each Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003175/batch-file-to-copy-every-line-in-txt-file-and-then-create-new-txt-file-for-eac)) about the problem, but only for one txt file i need to do it for a lot ;)

I hope my question is clear :)

Greetz Baff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"DOS prompts that my destination folder does not exist, but i
>   just created it with COPY NUL in the first for loop."*

No, you attempted to create a file, not a folder. And based on your reported error message, that attempt failed because the path you provided does not exist. I suspect a typing error - look carefully at the path you use in both the COPY and ECHO lines, and verify it actually exists. If it doesn't, then use `MD` or `MKDIR` to create it.

Note - you do not need to create an empty file before you append to it. `>>` will create the file if it does not exist already.

There is a simpler and much faster way to copy a file, skipping N lines, using MORE.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /a count=1
for %%a in ("C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\conduct\*.txt") do (
  echo %%a         
  more +3 "%%a" >"someOtherPathThatExists\conduct!count!.txt"
  set /a count+=1
)
pause
```

This technique has the following limitations:

- `<TAB>` characters are converted into a string of spaces
- MORE fails (hangs) if there are more than 64k lines in the file

Comment: Thanks for the hint, the actual error msg was : "The system cannot find the drive specified". Your proposed code works perfectly, also for my entered path. At the beginning i didnt use the COPY NUL to create an empty folder, but i just tried different things to make this code working. Thanks a lot for your answer!