# batch to copy File Name & FIRST line of multiple text files

Tags: batch-file

This code works great but I need to add the file name to the front of each line it writes.

How would this be done?

From Thread:
[batch to copy FIRST line of multiple text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19935669/batch-to-copy-first-line-of-multiple-text-files/19944265#19944265?newreg=c61ce650a0c547b0be5e333fc6f2e012)

---

This uses a helper batch file called findrepl.bat from - https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfdldmcb6vwi9xc/findrepl.bat

Place findrepl.bat in the same folder as the batch file or on the path.

```
@echo off
set linenum=1
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
   type "%%a"|findrepl /o:%linenum%:%linenum% >>tmp.tmp
)
move /y tmp.tmp "Result.txt"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off 
(
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
 set "first="
 for /f "usebackq delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do if not defined first (
  echo(%%a %%b
  set first=Y
 )
)
)>"Result.txt"
```

should work for you.

---

Into a new file named "Result.txt"
- For each-file (name to `%%a`)
--  clear a flag
--  read the file line-by-line to `%%b`; if the flag is clear `echo` the filename
   and line read and set the flag so that no further lines are reproduced

`usebackq` used because `%%a` is quoted. `%%a` is quoted in case it contains separator characters.

Comment: @bjb568 : I assume you're the source of the down-vote. I would claim that the question simply asks how to prepend the source filename to the extracted text from the batch presented. It is in fact a better structured question than many. My response shows how that can be done - in a manner which is probably easier. The response addresses the problem stated in the question title, so anyone wanting to display the filename and first line from multiple text files would find it. Hence it's of use to the wider community.

Comment: Please explain why your answer is a solution to the question.